# Print layout customization using angularjs 1.X in the UI before showing the print screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

We are trying to implement the print screen behavior by customizing the print layout. Explaining the feature in brief:
User will have an option to export as pdf. On click we are planning to provide a print layout where the user can set the margin, header and other widths from the UI something similar to the option provided by MS Word. Once the user customizes the layout he will download the document in the pdf format.
We are searching for a module which can actually help us in solving the problem to provide the layout and stuff. It will be great if we get some help.